# How to know what function (or code snippet) is triggered when an event happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I learn HTML and CSS by looking at the code on browsers with Firebug tool. If I can't understand what they do, I look up their reference. And I learned a lot.

Now I want to learn JavaScript in the same way (I just know  a litle bit about JS). Let's say:

1. I open a web page (e.g Facebook)
2. I click on setting button on the top right of the page. It shows a list of options (Account Setting, Privacy Settings, Log Out, ...)
3. I know the options box is an `<ul>` tag, and it will toggle show/hide when I click on the setting button.

As far as I know, if I want to test a JS snippet (using Firebug), I have to know at what point it should run through. But I am not a Facebook developer, I didn't write that code, so I can't guess that point.

How can I know what function is called to show the "options box" when I "click" on setting button?

Comment: If you use Chrome's dev tools , you can set a event breakpoint on the click which will take you to the function . Check out this vid with Paul Irish http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/ , it shows you how to do that and lots of other cool things .

Answer (score 6):

It's not a sure-fire answer but there might be a few ways to see if there are functions bound to elements and a vague idea of what they might do.

Firstly, Chrome's Firebug equivalent in the right pane (press <kbd>F12</kbd>, after *Inspecting* an element, scroll all the way down to the *Event Listeners* section and it will show the functions bound to that element.

If you are on Firefox there is an extension to Firebug called [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) which will actually annotate the DOM inspector in Firebug with links to the events which again is useful.

Lastly you might be able to load in the [jQuery-inlog](http://prinzhorn.github.com/jquery-inlog/) library to actually see exactly what jQuery is doing internally. This is probably the best bet since you don't have to set a breakpoint on anything. Just use the page as normal and the jQuery internal logging will show in the *Console*. You just need to inject the script on whatever page you want to inspect. On Firefox this could be done with Greasemonkey - see [Running custom Javascript on every page in Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778564/running-custom-javascript-on-every-page-in-mozilla-firefox) for more details.

Comment: Very useful advice for me, in particular the first part. It does not work well with minimized scripts and event-managing libraries in general, but it is better than scanning the source code.

Comment: If you ever have minimised scripts that need debugging, there is an option in Chrome on the _Scripts_ tab to "pretty print" the code allowing easy breakpoint setting and reading :-)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that option. Still that approach will only take you to the `addEventListener()` call, and with event-managing libraries the listener is a method argument. For example, on StackOverflow's "add comment" button you find a listener for the `click` event.  And showing the source code gets you to `f.event.add()` with arguments `a`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `g`, where somewhere along the way one of those is used for defining `i` which is then used in the call. So you do not really get to the listener this way, but it helps finding it *iff* you can see through the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the developer used standards-compliant event-handler attributes, this is not a trivial task.

The element that you click, or one of its ancestors (because the `click` event bubbles), has most certainly identifying attributes (e.g., `id` and `class`) so that event listeners can be easily added to it. Look out for the event type names (e.g., `click`) and values of those identifying attributes in the script code then.

If the developer used (often standards-compliant) event-handler attributes or proprietary event-handler properties (like `onclick`), you should see the (clickable) function values of those in a DOM inspector (like Firebug's). But that is less likely nowadays.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I saw some websites and lots of them were written by native Javascript, not jQuery

Comment: You're welcome. But what do you mean by "native Javascript" ([there is no "Javascript"](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix))? Contrary to common misconception, jQuery is written in "native JavaScript" (for fitting values of "JavaScript"; I prefer "ECMAScript implementations"), and very bad written, too. This is *not* a matter of programming language or framework.

Comment: sorry, I mean "pure javascript", I am newbie in JS, and I start with jQuery, not "pure JS". jQuery's functions help my code much more cleaner and easy too debug and maintain. I am trying to manage and optimize my code. All my JS code now are actually very bad.

Comment: There is no "javascript" either. Re: this and jQuery: Suffice it to say you have a lot to (un)learn.