# Javascript: How to know what function being runned at a DOM when I resize the window?

Tags: javascript, browser

When I adjust my window's size, I notice the css style changed accordingly:

[image]

However, I don't know what function is responsible for this. Is there anyway I can know what function is runned when I resize the window?

---

I find [How to know what function (or code snippet) is triggered when an event happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769695/how-to-know-what-function-or-code-snippet-is-triggered-when-an-event-happens)

But the jQuery-log seems not working in this page. I'm trying FireQuery right now.

Comment: What browser dev tools are you asking for help with?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm using firefox

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome has a function called getEventListeners. When you enter the dev tools just open the console and type in:

```
getEventListeners(window)
```

This should show you the event listener of the window object. Now take a look at the resize handlers.