# Linking a particular website with a JavaScript in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

Can I attach a JavaScript written by me for a particular web page in firefox?

So whenever I open that web page (or whole site) the JavaScript(written specifically for that web page) starts automatically (without doing it manually using alt+shift+k in firefox and then entering it in the console).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778564/running-custom-javascript-on-every-page-in-mozilla-firefox

Comment: Are you writing a Firefox extension and/or is this a programming question of any kind? (Side note, I'm not an native speaker but I don't think the word "JavaScript" is countable: one JavaScript, two JavaScripts...)

Comment: Check out Greasemonkey: http://www.greasespot.net/

Comment: Thanks! greasemonkey helped me to do what I wanted .